# package scanning skipping mapper files in jar file

Tags: java, mybatis

Package scanning seems to be skipping mapper files packaged in a jar file.

For example:

```
<mappers>
  <!-- Doesn't work when I package my project as a JAR. -->
  <package name="testmy.sqlmaps" />
  <!-- Works even when mapper files are in a JAR file. -->
  <!--mapper class="testmy.sqlmaps.TestMyMapper" /-->
  <!--mapper class="testmy.sqlmaps.MySecondMapper" /-->
</mappers>
```

Things work properly when I run my project via Eclipse or via command line as an "exploded jar", but if I export my app from Eclipse as a jar and then run it via command line then I get the following stack trace:

```
org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException: Type interface testmy.sqlmaps.TestMyMapper is not known to the MapperRegistry.
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperRegistry.getMapper(MapperRegistry.java:47)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.Configuration.getMapper(Configuration.java:675)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.getMapper(DefaultSqlSession.java:250)
    at testmy.dao.TestMyDAO.testMyBatisQuery(TestMyDAO.java:9)
    at testmy.batch.TestMybatis.main(TestMybatis.java:17)
```

It's as if `ResolverUtil` is either skipping my application jar or doesn't know to look inside for goodies.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem with the kind help of the Mybatis user group.

This issue arises when the "Add directory entries" checkbox is unchecked on the "JAR File Specification" step while exporting the project as a jar file in Eclipse. Ensuring the checkbox is checked solved the problem.